# Strange Problem of Encoding URL leading to a Forbidden Message from Browser

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer

Get ready for some strangeness. The following works fine in Firefox:

Redirecting to this URL:

```
http://localhost/webs/van/front-end/slr/edit_rule.php?rule_name=test&rule_type=alloc_ext&copy=1
```

However, it does not work in IE8 since it converts the above to this, note the copyright symbol in the address at the end:

```
http://localhost/webs/van/front-end/slr/edit_rule.php?rule_name=test&rule_type=alloc_ext©=1
```

So, I thought weird, lets just `encodeURIComponent` to this:

```
window.location.href = 'edit_rule.php%3Frule_name%3Dtest%26rule_type%3Dalloc_ext%26copy%3D1';
```

BOTH, Firefox and IE8 now give me a Forbidden message!?!

> You don't have permission to access /webs/van/front-end/slr/edit_rule.php? rule_name=test2&rule_type=alloc_ext&copy=1 on this server.

I don't understand, what is going on?

Thanks all for any help.

Comment: `&copy;` is the HTML entity for the copyright symbol: &copy; Internet Explorer, being a Microsoft product, tries to encumber you with help, converting the incomplete entity to a complete one just when it will do the most damage.

Comment: @Robusto you're totally right, but to be fair, using the proper `&amp;` which circumvents the problem *is* the W3C valid way.

Comment: I think I might have just got it to work with just `encodeURI` instead of `encodeURIComponent`!

Comment: @Pekka: A fair point, which is why when I construct query strings using Javascript I'm inclined to create them in arrays which I then join with the '&' character. Literal strings can be problematic, as illustrated by this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&` needs to be [HTML encoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html), not URI encoded.  Specifically, replace them with `&amp;`

Technically, IE8's behavior is wrong, as `&copy` is missing the semicolon at the end to make it an HTML-encoded character.

Comment: I just tried that out and I get the same message. The forbidden message now shows `&` as `&amp;`.

Comment: @Abs you need to remove the `encodeURIComponent`. That is for components only, you mustn't encode the whole query string with it

Comment: @Pekka - Ah I see! That works, I guess I have to convert that URL now since PHP is unable to pick on the GET variables.

Comment: Simpler solution, don't even bother using the `copy` GET variable, its now called `lcopy`. Thanks for the advice about HTML encoding the `&` - I did not know that.

Comment: Why would you encode the ampersand? It's being used as the separator for the 'copy' query string variable. It would need to be encoded if it were part of the variable name or value. Sounds like changing the name to get rid of bug is the best idea.

Comment: @Juan: Because HTML uses the & character as a special character.  Using & directly causes HTML validation errors, whereas using &amp; doesn't.  To put it in medical terms, it's addressing the cause rather than the symptom.

Comment: @ R.Bemrose: In his example, he's setting it from javascript, there's no need to encode html characters in your javascript code. So I don't think you're addressing the cause, I think you're also patching around the issue. I think the real cause is IE8's mishandling of the url;

Answer (score 0):

IE8 most likely tries to change &copy to copyright symbol - `&copy;` ©
Changing parameter name would be an easy fix to do.

I also see a space in the error message you posted after question mark before rule_name, may be it causes some weiredness.

Comment: That is just my copy and pasting, there is no space or line break there. Apologies.